# Using Cypress tests how to select a feature on a map location

Tags: automated-testing, cypress

We have an app where we can display dataset features on an Open Layers map page.  These dataset features are then selectable to allow further attributes of these datasets to be displayed.

In my Cypress tests I've done most of my testing using the DOM element to identify, but when I select the map window I just get `canvas.ol-unselectable` which doesn't show the dataset features.
I think I can use x,y co-ordinates to find a location on the page, but what do I use in the `cy.get()`.Is there an option to select the browser window?

Answer (score 1):

```
    cy.get('canvas').trigger('pointerdown', {clientX: 900, clientY: 500})
    cy.get('canvas').trigger('pointerup', {clientX: 900,clientY: 500})
```

Comment: It's helping me select polygon features, but I'm still having issues with point locations, but I think that is more to do with having to provide exact x,y locations.  So, Yes, I'm happy that this solution has worked.